# postgresql error when import dump

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I got sql dump from my client, and this is a port of the sql dump script generated from postgresql

```
--
-- EnterpriseDB database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.1.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.1.5

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET edb_redwood_date = off;
SET default_with_rowids = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

.
. Till Then so long here
.

COPY inittemp (terminalid, tracenumber, createat, data, flag) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: tbaid; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: tmsedc
--

COPY tbaid (aidid, appvernum, aidname, tacdefault, tacdenial, taconline, threshold, target, maxtarget, defaultddol, defaulttdol, bankacqid, floorlimit, categorycode, trxtype, terminalcapability, indicatortag, databaseid, status, isapproved, approveddate, approvedby, cardtype) FROM stdin;
asd s   s   s   0   0   0.0.0.0 0   0   750 s   s   s   s   s   s   s   1   Y   Y   2018-06-29 10:20:23.174239  ayao    s
2222    s   222 s   0   0   0.0.0.0 0   0   750 s   s   s   s   s   s   s   1   Y   Y   2018-06-29 11:25:39.504868  ayao    s
11  11  11  0   0   0   0.0.0.0 0   0   750 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   N   Y   2018-06-29 10:21:05.103313  ayao    1
0001    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  1   Y   Y   \N  \N  xxxxx
\.
```

this is my first error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 5301: \.
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 243732
```

i erased `\.` and got another error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "asd"
LINE 5309: asd s s s 0 0 0.0.0.0 0 0 750 s s s s s s s 1 Y Y 2018-06-29...
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 244104
```

I used postgresql 10.4 for osx, and i use execute query to import this dump.

please help me how to solve this?

oh yeah additional question, is enterpriseDB and postgresql same?

Comment: You can't use "execute query" to import the dump. You need to use the command line tool psql to run that script, e.g. `psql -U postgres -f dump_file.sql`

Comment: okay let me try